# Support for Spring 3.0.6 and upgrade to 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have application using various libraries including Spring 3.0.6. It uses WLS 12 server, Java7, Hibernate 3.6.1.

**I have such libraries:**

- spring-core-3.0.6
- spring-webflow-2.0.7
- spring-batch-core-2.1.7
- spring-context-3.0.6
- other spring libs of a bit minor importance

Now I am only talking about Spring.I am wondering if it is reasonable to invest some time to upgrade to Spring 4. I need to justify it using some strong arguments. Everything works in our project so there is no straight reason for updating, however I think projects should follow library updates if possible.

**My questions are**

0) Are there some conflicts between Spring 4 and Hibernate 3.0.6,upgrading Spring would mean upgrading Hibernate?

1) Is there something like support for bugs in Spring 3 ? No support would be an argument in favour of upgrading. Are they fixing bugs in 3 version or always do fixes in newest minor versions?

2) What features could be brought by Spring 4 that every PM should be interested in?

3) What other arguments would u bring?

Comment: This site is for asking specific questions about programming, not opinions on updates, programs, etc.

Comment: Oh sorry, didnt know that, I've seen plenty of ugrading questions here so posted mine, I may delete if it is a must.

Comment: No worries--live and learn. Specific questions about updates are not necessarily out of the question for this site, but this question is probably a little too broad. The moderators will decide one way or the other if you take no action. I think you could find answers to most of your questions on Spring's website (at least 0-2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend updating Hibernate before you think about updating to Spring 4. Spring 4 deprecated support for Hibernate 3. They themselves also recommend the update, you can read more [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-from-earlier-versions-of-the-spring-framework)

> The org.springframework.orm.hibernate3 package will be deprecated as of Spring Framework 4.2. We keep fully supporting it for the time being against Spring Framework 4.0 and 4.1. However, we recommend a timely upgrade to Hibernate 4.2/4.3.

Comment: One more question - what should be the order of upgrade: Spring3.0.6 to 4, Hibernate 3.6.1 to 5, Java 7 to 8

Comment: Hibernate -> Spring -> Java

Comment: Wow. why Java last? I thought it could be first...

Comment: Java last to ensure nobody in your team starts making use of Java 8 features, in libraries that do not support them.